# GitHub Projects - How to set issue status based on card column?

Tags: github, github-issues

Within a GitHub "Project", is it possible to change the status of an issue when I move a card (which is an issue) to a certain column (in this case "Done")?

Example in image - I would like to move "fooo barrr" to the "Done" column and close the issue:

[image: Doing and Done columns etc]

I know I can click "fooo barrr" and open the issue and close it, but it would be nice to kind of synchronise the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this option unlikely to exist, because it is an unusual workflow for agile methodologies (the ones that popularized this "post-it" approach to handling issues). If you are working by yourself and just want this functionality for personal purposes, you could use this [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-projects-trello-li/cpdlcidglpjlcamneedpcbjbkffigkhg/related). It opens the issue form on the same page and allows you to close it without having to leave.

The idea behind the columns is to provide a big picture to all collaborators. Moving an issue to "Done" serves the purpose of telling your workmates that work has been done and, now, they can work on stuff that requires it. It doesn't necessarily mean it has been closed (as in everything has been completely dealt with), only that they don't need to worry about it anymore.

Comment: Yeah I think I see your point, and where it would get messy if everyone had different definitions of done. In the end (since writing that question) I have moved back to Bitbucket, its integration with things like jira worked a lot better